# Pylint dependency error

Tags: pylint

I am getting following error while running pylint traceback. I don't understand what this error is. Can any one solve this problem?

```
[root@c4t22472 common-model-python]# pylint Traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pylint", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('pylint==1.6.4', 'console_scripts', 'pylint')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pylint-1.6.4-py2.6.egg/pylint/__init__.py", line 12, in run_pylint
from pylint.lint import Run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pylint-1.6.4-py2.6.egg/pylint/lint.py", line 739
filter_options = {'long-help'}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Python 2.6. Unfortunately, recent versions of Pylint support only 2.7+.